# When Outlook is restarted the connection to the exchange server gets refused

Tags: microsoft-outlook, exchange

I have a problem. Most of the time, when I need to restart the outlook application on a client, the connection to the local Exchange Server (2016) is not made anymore. If I leave the client for some minutes it will connect. Also when I wait for around 10 minutes in between closing outlook and restarting it again, the problem will not ocurr.

The problem is not related to a specific user. But it seems, that the problem occurs more on users with a lot of other mailboxes.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

Based on your description, here are some questions on your issue:

1. Do your outlook in cache mode?
2. What are the versions of your outlook clients?
3. Do you try to upgrade your outlook clients to the latest version and check if this issue continues?
4. Run outlook in safe mode, check if this issue caused by add-ins.
5. Run [EXRCA](https://testconnectivity.microsoft.com/tests/Ola/input) to test outlook connectivity.

In addition, follow the steps mentioned in this [article](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/topic/how-to-troubleshoot-performance-issues-in-outlook-7ac5402d-c4eb-ed6b-9545-b26dde618755) for further troubleshooting.

Comment: Thank you for your input:

1. Yes, Outlook is running in cache mode.

2. The Outlook is running 2019 (but the same error was on 
Outlook 2010, from this I think it's a server thing)
3. The Outlook Clients are all on the latest patch level.

4. The problem stays the same, even in safe mode.

5. EXRCA is not possible, because the firewall only allow connections from within this country.

I will check the last link as soon as possible.

Comment: Do you mean that your outlook only connect to exchange internally? If so, you could run test email AutoConfiguration to check the detailed information on autodiscover.